# using .all() in views and for loop in template shows all content created from Album model

Tags: django, django-models

I have two model: `Album` and `Primary` model, I want to submit `Primary` model using pure `Html Form` but as you can see in the `Primary` model there is a field that has a relationship with a `Album` model using `ForeignKey`, when user is trying to create `Primary` model in form he\she may sees all the content that is created in the `Album` model using this method:

```
def primary_submit_form(request):
        albums = Album.objects.all()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            admisssion_number = request.POST['admisssion_number']
            profile_picture = request.FILES['profile_picture']
            first_name = request.POST['first_name']
            sure_name = request.POST['sure_name']
            gender = request.POST['gender']
            
            student_create = Primary.objects.create(
                admisssion_number=admisssion_number, profile_picture=profile_picture,
                first_name=first_name, sure_name=sure_name, gender=gender,
                year_of_graduations=year_of_graduations
                )
            
    
            student_create.save()
    
            return redirect('Primary-Albums')
        return render(request, 'create_primary_student_information.html')
```

My templates:

```
    <select class="form-select"\>
        {% for album in albums %}
    <option value="1"\>{{album.name}}\</option\>
        {% endfor %}
    </select\>
```

my models:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name   

class Primary(models.Model):
    addminssion_number = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    profilePicture = models.ImageField(upload_to='image')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    sure_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=25)  
    year_of_graduations = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How can i allow user to create primary model without seeing all album that is created by other's user, i dont want my user to see the content that he\she does not create. I knew using `.all()` method in `views` and `for loop` in template would shows all content that is created from Album model, but i don't want that, i want user to see the only content that he\she is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem using `QuerySet` with `.filter(user=request.user)`.

The QuerySet returned by all() describes all objects in the database table. Usually, though, you’ll need to select only a subset of the complete set of objects.

Here is how i did it:

```
def primary_submit_form(request):
        
        albums = Album.objects.filter(user=request.user)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            admisssion_number = request.POST['admisssion_number']
            profile_picture = request.FILES['profile_picture']
            first_name = request.POST['first_name']
            sure_name = request.POST['sure_name']
            gender = request.POST['gender']
            
            student_create = Primary.objects.create(
                admisssion_number=admisssion_number, profile_picture=profile_picture,
                first_name=first_name, sure_name=sure_name, gender=gender,
                year_of_graduations=year_of_graduations
                )
            
    
            student_create.save()
    
            return redirect('Primary-Albums')
        return render(request, 'create_primary_student_information.html')


  [1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/
```